# Powershell CSV modification

Tags: powershell, csv

CSV source exemple:

```
"Requested Quantity","Unit of Measure","Requested Date","Forecast Timing Qualifier","Rating"
"4.00 ","EA","26.09.2022","W","DOA1"
"12.00 ","EA","27.09.2022","W","DOA1"
```

I need to remove the last 3 Characters to `Requested Quantity` and
I need to convert the `Requested Date` format to `Month.Day.Year` for each line.

Input : `"4.00 ","EA","26.09.2022","W","DOA1"`
Output : `"4","EA","09/26/2022","W","DOA1"`

I got the Requested quantity ok but I need some help with converting the date portion.

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `Requested Quantity` column you can use the `-replace` operator to remove the dot and everything after. For the date column, use `[Datetime]::ParseExact()` to parse the existing format, then convert back to a string with the desired format:

```
Import-Csv path\to\source.csv |ForEach-Object {
    # Cut the trailing decimals off the quantity
    $_.'Requested Quantity' = $_.'Requested Quantity' -replace '\..*$'

    # Parse and re-format date column
    $_.'Requested Date' = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Requested Date', 'dd.MM.yyyy', $null).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')

    # output the modified object for export
    $_
} |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The output I get is not correct for the date.  "4","EA","09-26-2022","W","DOA1" It looks like it take my system date separators not /

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track Mathias.  I ended up changing the Request Date Parse to   # Parse and re-format date column
    $_.'Requested Date' = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Requested Date', 'dd.MM.yyyy', $null).ToString('MM\/dd\/yyyy') to get it to work correctly.